# Physical meaning for the determinant of the stress energy tensor?

Tags: field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I wonder if there is any physical meaning associated to the determinant of the stress energy tensor. Or do we know at least some context in which this quantity is meaningful?

Comment: Could you sketch some background for this question? Why do you expect it to be meaningful?

Comment: For example if it appears in some equation relating it to other physical objects, or if you can explain some physical notion using it. As an example, metric desribes distances in spacetime, while (the square root of) its determinant describes the volume element. And the volume element is meaningful in its own as it appears in many different physical equations such as dE=P dV, etc.